# How do I check for ID equality

Tags: javascript

If I say...

```
alert(this.id);
```

I get an alert that says "info". How do I do a...

```
if(this.id == "info") alert("Info");
```

Also,

```
if(this.is("#info")) alert ("Info");
```

did not work.

Comment: What's wrong with `if(this.id == "info") alert("Info");`? You could do `if($(this).attr("id") == "info") alert("Info");`.

Comment: I couldn't tell you... That's why I was asking.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try `if(this.id == "info") alert("Info");`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a live demo?

Comment: What you've got should work. You're going to have to show us more code (are you sure `this` is pointing to the same object all the time?)

Comment: Your first attempt works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/uuApY/

Comment: being able to see the html markup that goes with this code would be extremely helpful. Do you have some stray whitespace in your id maybe? something like `<div id=" info">`?

Comment: you should add the output of `console.log(this)` so people can see what "this" is referring to in context.

Comment: I'm betting that @MrOBrian has it pegged. I would almost guarantee that there is some whitespace that isn't seen when alerting the ID.

Comment: The code does in fact work. I was viewing an older version in my tests. Flagging question for removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `if(this.getAttribute('id') == "info") alert("Info");` Or maybe `this` is not an object then there is additional code from your side needed to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use attr("id").

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PJDkk/1/

Comment: His code *should* work (http://jsfiddle.net/uuApY/). If what he's got isn't working, it'll be some *miracle* if this does.